# DataMapper - Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby, sinatra, single-table-inheritance, ruby-datamapper

Could Some one please explain to me what is going on here?

This is an example that I put together to show y'all whats up:

```
class Person
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :type, Discriminator
  property :name, String
  property :age, Integer
end

class Male < Person
end

class Father < Male
  property :job, String
end

class Son < Male
end

class Female < Person
end

class Mother < Female
  property :favorite_song, String
end

class Daughter < Female
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

If I call `Person.all` I get:

```
Person.all
=> [#<Son @id=1 @type=Son @name="Mike" @age=23 @status=nil>, 
#<Son @id=2 @type=Son @name="Carlos" @age=12 @status=nil>, 
#<Father @id=3 @type=Father @name="Robert" @age=55 @job=<not loaded>>, 
#<Mother @id=4 @type=Mother @name="Wanda" @age=47 @status=nil @favorite_song=<not loaded>>, 
#<Daughter @id=5 @type=Daughter @name="Meg" @age=16 @status=nil>]
```

And if I call `Person.get(3).type` I get:

```
Person.get(3).type
=> Father
```

And `Male.all` gives me this:

```
Male.all
=> [#<Son @id=1 @type=Son @name="Mike" @age=23 @status=nil>, 
#<Son @id=2 @type=Son @name="Carlos" @age=12 @status=nil>, 
#<Father @id=3 @type=Father @name="Robert" @age=55 @job=<not loaded>>]
```

And `Male.get(3).type` gives this:

```
Male.get(3).type
=> Father
```

But `Person.all(:type => Male)` returns an empty array: (?)

```
Person.all(:type => Male)
=> []
```

However, `Person.all(:type => Son)` returns all of the `Son` type entries (=/)

```
Person.all(:type => Son)
=> [#<Son @id=1 @type=Son @name="Mike" @age=23 @status=nil>,
#<Son @id=2 @type=Son @name="Carlos" @age=12 @status=nil>]
```

If I try do do something like `@person = People.all` I get all entries in @person exactly as you would expect. but I cannot do something like `@men = @person.all(:type => Male)` I get an empty array.

```
@men = @people.all( :type => Male)
=> []
```

I would be using this with Sinatra. What I would like is to be able to for example grab all of my people in one gram from the DB and hold them in `@people` but still be able to sort/filter them for various uses in my views. I have done something similar with associations before and it worked rather well. But I would like to try STI because it seems to be a more concise way to deal with my data.

I have noticed things as well that if I do something like `@women = Female.all` I get all of the woman, but if I do something like `@woman.each do |woman|` I am unable to access contain properties in my views (i.e. `woman.favorite_song` returns nothing).

Am I missing something about how this works? I do not understand what is going on here at all and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the SQL that's being generated it gives you a clue as to what's going on (if you don't know, you can do this with `DataMapper::Logger.new(STDOUT, :debug)` *before* your call to `DataMapper::setup`).

`Person.all` simply generates:

```sql
SELECT "id", "type", "name", "age" FROM "people" ORDER BY "id"
```

as you would expect.

`Male.all` generates:

```sql
SELECT "id", "type", "name", "age" FROM "people"
  WHERE "type" IN ('Male', 'Father', 'Son') ORDER BY "id"
```

and `Person.all(:type => Male)` generates:

```sql
SELECT "id", "type", "name", "age" FROM "people"
  WHERE "type" = 'Male' ORDER BY "id"
```

So when you use `Male.all` Datamapper knows to create an SQL `IN` clause containing the names of all the appropriate classes, but when you use `Person.all(:type => Male)` uses *just* the type you specify and none of the subclasses.

A similar direct comparison must be happening when you query a collection rather than the database with `@people.all(:type => Male)`.

In order to correctly get all subclasses of a type in a query you can use the [`descendants` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.1.0/DataMapper/Model#descendants-class_method).

`People.all(:type => Male.descendants)` generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT "id", "type", "name", "age" FROM "people"
  WHERE "type" IN ('Father', 'Son') ORDER BY "id"
```

In this case this will return what you want, but note that the `IN` clause doesn't contain `Male`, it's only the descendants of the model, not including the parent of the subtree in question.

To get the 'top' class as well, you could use:

```ruby
Person.all(:type => Male.descendants.dup << Male)
```

to add the `Male` class to the `IN` clause. Note the `dup` is needed, otherwise you'll get  `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`.

This will also work on collections as expected:

```ruby
@people.all(:type => Male.descendants.dup << Male)
```

will return all males without hitting the database (assuming `@people` already contains all the people).

If you do decide to use the `descendants` method, note that although it isn't marked as private in the docs, it's marked [`@api semipublic`](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb#L45) in the source, so look out when upgrading Datamapper. The [`<<` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-core/1.2.0/DataMapper/DescendantSet#%3C%3C-instance_method) in `Male.descendants.dup << Male` *is* marked as private, so the warning applies even more here. I got this usage from the [source to Discriminator](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-core/property/discriminator.rb#L41).

---

#### Missing properties

Your other issue about not being able to get certain properties looks like it's something to do with lazy loading, but I can't work out exactly what's going on. It might be a bug.

When you load all females with `@women = Female.all` the SQL generated is:

```sql
SELECT "id", "type", "name", "age" FROM "people"
  WHERE "type" IN ('Female', 'Mother', 'Daughter') ORDER BY "id"
```

so only attributes possessed by all members are fetched. The `favorite_song` of mothers is then fetched the first time you reference it. The lines:

```ruby
puts women.first.inspect
puts women.first.favorite_song
puts women.first.inspect
```

give (including the SQL log showing when the missing value is fetched):

```
#<Mother @id=4 @type=Mother @name="Wanda" @age=47 @favorite_song=<not loaded>>
 ~ (0.000069) SELECT "id", "type", "favorite_song" FROM "people" WHERE "id" = 4 ORDER BY "id"
Suspicious minds
#<Mother @id=4 @type=Mother @name="Wanda" @age=47 @favorite_song="Suspicious minds">
```

However, when I do something similar in an `each` block, the query to fetch the missing value doesn't incude the `favorite_song`, and the value is set to nil in the model:

```ruby
women.each do |w|
  next unless w.respond_to? :favorite_song
  puts w.inspect
  puts w.favorite_song
  puts w.inspect
end
```

gives the output (again including the SQL):

```
#<Mother @id=4 @type=Mother @name="Wanda" @age=47 @favorite_song=<not loaded>>
 ~ (0.000052) SELECT "id", "type" FROM "people" WHERE "type" IN ('Female', 'Mother', 'Daughter') ORDER BY "id"

#<Mother @id=4 @type=Mother @name="Wanda" @age=47 @favorite_song=nil>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something here, or if this is indeed a bug.

Comment: Wow! thanks what a fantastic answer! thanks! I figured that it had something to do with the underlying SQL / parent/child/descendent relationships. and/or the way I was trying to request in data. Thanks so much!

Comment: As for the Missing Properties issue, Do you think that I should submit a bug report?

Comment: @DonGraziano Sorry for the late reply. I found this: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/issues/46 that seems to be the same issue. It's an old bug that's been closed, but doesn't look like a fix was made. It could well be worth opening a new bug. At the least you could get an explanation for what's happening.

Comment: Wow! Excellent answer matt. +1